# Ember.js acceptance test check inputs' values

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, acceptance-testing

I have a lot of logic in a big form, where input values depend on each other. I am trying to test values of these inputs.

In this case `find("#sales_price").val()` results in empty string:

```
fillIn("#sales_price", 12345);
andThen(function() {
  assert.equal(find("#sales_price").val(),123456);
...
```

In such example binding stops to work and `find("#sales_price").val()` gets initial value of input (but not 12345):

```
find("#sales_price").val(12345);
andThen(function() {
  assert.equal(find("#sales_price").val(),123456);
...
```

Comment: How about calling change after you change the val; what I mean is:
`find("#sales_price").change();`

Comment: Thx, for help, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make bindings work:

```
fillIn("#sales_price", 123456);
find("#sales_price").change();

andThen(function() {
  assert.equal(find("#sales_price").val(),123456);
...
```